# Why does entanglement negativity not satisfy the triangle inequality in the usual sense?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer, linear-algebra

I am a bit puzzled, I’ve read in some places, like the [original paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/488645/) by Vidal, that
$$
\mathcal{N}(\sum_n a_n \rho_n)\leq \sum_n a_n \mathcal{N}(\rho_n)
$$
**whenever $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum_n a_n =1$**. I am guessing the more general inequality holds too:
$$
\mathcal{N}(\sum_n a_n \rho_n)\leq \sum_n |a_n| \mathcal{N}(\rho_n), \tag{1}
$$
for **any** $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$, not just $a_n\geq 0$. This should follow from the standard operator norm properties and the original paper was likely just thinking about a general mixed state than a general operator.

Am I missing something? Is expression (1) correct?

NB: $\mathcal{N}(\rho) = (||\rho^{T_A}||_1-1)/2$, with $||\cdot||_1$ the trace norm.

---

Edit: As pointed out by user glS expression (1) holds provided that $\sum_n |a_n| \leq 1$.

Comment: No, It is not valid in general...Try to derive it from standard operator norm and  taking that $-1$ into account. You see that $\sum_n a_n =1$ plays a role...

Comment: How many examples did you try to see whether (1) is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n\in\mathbb C$ be generic complex coefficients. The convexity and (positive) homogeneity of the trace norm then tells you that
$$\mathcal N(\rho)
= \mathcal N(\sum_n a_n \rho_n)
\equiv \frac12 \left(\bigg\|\sum_n a_n \rho_n^{T_A}\bigg\|_1-1\right)
\le \frac12 \left(\sum_n |a_n|\, \|\rho_n^{T_A}\|_1-1\right).$$
Therefore if $a_n\ge0$ and $\sum_n a_n=1$, then you can conclude that
$$\mathcal N(\rho) \le \sum_n a_n \mathcal N(\rho_n),$$
but this is not true in general.

As a trivial counterexample, take any separable state $\rho$, *e.g.* $\rho=|00\rangle\!\langle00|$, and $a\in\mathbb C$. Then
$$\mathcal N(a\rho)=\frac{\|a\rho\|_1-1}{2}=\frac{|a|-1}{2},
\qquad
\mathcal |a| N(\rho) = |a|\frac{\|\rho\|_1-1}{2} = 0,$$
and thus whenever $|a|>1$ you have $\mathcal N(a\rho)>|a|\mathcal N(\rho)=0$.

Comment: Shouldn’t the statement be that $|a_n|\geq 0$ and $\sum_n |a_n| \leq 1$? My reasoning comes from $$\frac{1}{2}(\sum_n |a_n| ||\rho_n^{T_A}||_1-1)=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_n|a_n|||\rho^{T_a}_n||_1-\sum_n|a_n|+\sum_n|a_n|-1)=\sum_n |a_n|(\frac{||\rho_n^{T_A}||_1-1}{2})+\frac{1}{2}(\sum_n|a_n|-1)$$ thus $$  \mathcal{N}(\sum_n a_n \rho_n) \leq \sum_n |a_n|\mathcal{N}(\rho_n) + \frac{1}{2}(\sum_n|a_n|-1).$$

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian which statement are you referring to? Your calculation seems fine to me; it doesn't contradict my answer

Comment: The condition for the inequality in your answer is that $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum_n a_n =1$ (right after *Therefore if..*). I reasoned that the somewhat weaker $|a_n|\geq 0$ and $\sum_n |a_n| \leq 1$ is also valid. No?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian I don't understand what you are saying. For one thing, $|a_n|\ge0$ is not a condition, it's always trivially true. Regardless, you gave the modified inequality that works in the general case. If you mean that for $\sum|a_n|\le1$ you also get the one in the original post, then yes, I agree.

Comment: So Im guessing that the $a_n \geq 0$ condition is just so that we can write $\sum_n |a_n| \rho_n$ as $\sum_n a_n\rho_n$. Sorry for the extensive comments and thank you so much!

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian I guess you can say that, yes. But also, when talking about "convexity" one also always refers to positive coefficients

Answer (score 0):

$a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum_n a_n = 1$ is a condition making $\sum_n a_n \rho_n$ a so-called convex combination and a little bit stronger than what you would need. You can derive (1) using $\sum_n \left|a_n\right| = 1$ and properties that any norm has by definition.